# My loop doesn't end when the condition is true

Tags: java

My program prompts the user to input an item's code. Duplicate codes are not allowed so when he enters the code, the `for` loop will checks if it exists. The `for` loop should `break` for my condition because I do get the output "Item's code exists" but it still does not add the item to the array. What am I missing?

```
tems[] items = new Items[200];
AddItem add = new AddItem();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int z,x;
double c,v;
String n,m,b;
public void addItem(){
    int r;
    z = add.getCode();
    x = add.getQuantity();
    c = add.getCostPrice();
    n = add.getDescription();
    m = add.getDiscount();
    v = add.getSellingPrice();
    b = add.getStatus();

    for(r = 0; r < items.length; r++){
        for(int q=0; q<r; q++){
            if(z==items[q].getCode()){
                System.out.println("Item's code exists");
                break;
            }
        }
        if(items[r]==null){
            items[r] = new Items(z, n, x, c, v, b, m);
            break;
        }else if (items[r]!=null){
            continue;
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the inner most loop - the `for( int q`

Comment: You must separate the for loop in a boolean function

Comment: and please improve your variable names.. And they should be locals to the function, not globals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to `break` the outer loop, use a [labeled break](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). Something like,

```
out: for(r = 0; r < items.length; r++){
  for(int q=0; q<r; q++){
    if(z==items[q].getCode()){
      System.out.println("Item's code exists");
      break out;
    }
  }
```

Comment: its my first time seeing "out". thx its worked. but one more question, can i use it in other things, other than the for loop? or this is the only use for it?

Comment: @mazin Click on the link in my answer for the tutorial topic, but a short answer is labels can be used for *`switch`*, *`break` / `continue`*, *`for`*, *`while`* and *`do-while`*. Also, `out` can be any label you care for.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little difficult to understand. Try improving variable names and creating comments so others can understand code better. I *Believe* the problem lies in your loops. The break statement breaks out of the first for loop, but it will not break out of both. If i am understanding your code, then it would be better to place a flag to properly break out of both loops.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using break is using a boolean variable :

```
boolean codeExists = false;
for(r = 0; r < items.length && !codeExists; r++){
    for(int q=0; q<r && !codeExists; q++){
        if(z==items[q].getCode()) {
            System.out.println("Item's code exists");
            codeExists = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Both loops would be exited once `codeExists` becomes true.